# Tem como executar essas funções do PHP via HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Tem como executar essas funções do PHP via HTML?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <title>Dispara condição no PHP</title>
    <link href="css/seu-stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="scripts/seu-script.js">

    // Função que dispara a if(isset($_POST['LP1'])){ if($msg[0]=='1') { $msg[0]='0'; } else { $msg[0]='1'; }} no php 
    function executaLP1()
    {                   }
    // Função que dispara a if(isset($_POST['LP2'])){ if($msg[0]=='1') { $msg[0]='0'; } else { $msg[0]='1'; }} no php 
    function executaLP2()
    {                   }

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <!--Botões que produzem o mesmo efeito daqueles do PHP-->
    <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="executaLP1"/>
    <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="executaLP2"/>

</body>

</html>
```

O PHP:

```
<?php
//Tenho esse código em php
   if(isset($_POST['dado'])) {
        $msg = $_POST['dado'];
        if(isset($_POST['LP1'])){ if($msg[0]=='1') { $msg[0]='0'; } else { $msg[0]='1'; }}
        if(isset($_POST['LP2'])){ if($msg[1]=='1') { $msg[1]='0'; } else { $msg[1]='1'; }}

        //Com esses 02 botões abaixo
        //Ao clicar no primeiro botão, executamos a condição LP1 e ao clicar no outro, executamos a condição LP2. 
        echo "<button style=\"width:966; height:150; color:#FF8040; background-color: $cor1 ;font: bold 50px Arial\" type = \"Submit\" Name = \"LP1\">Botão 01</button></br></br>";
        echo "<button style=\"width:966; height:150; color:#FF8040; background-color: $cor2 ;font: bold 50px Arial\" type = \"Submit\" Name = \"LP2\">Botão 02</button></br></br>";

     // Minha dúvida é a seguinte:
    //  Tem como executar essas mesmas condições só que com botões em HTML com auxílio do JS ou jQuery?
       //   Acima, fiz o código em HTML só para compreensão das ideias. Se houver como fazer isso sem a página atualizar, seria excelente!
?>
```

[Postei o fragmento do código no github para maior clareza!](https://gist.github.com/JurandirHora/a9a34a322d9a14a68bd866ed074d9467)

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:
Tem como executar essas mesmas condições só que com botões em HTML com auxílio do JS ou jQuery?

Acima, fiz o código em HTML só para compreensão das ideias. Se houver como fazer isso sem a página atualizar, seria excelente!

Comment: Olá Jurandir, seja bem vindo ao SOPT. Apenas uma dica, mas é sempre melhor postar o código aqui mesmo. Eu editei pra vc (isso é normal aqui), veja como ficou bom. :) É só colar o código, selecionar tudo e dar um Ctrl K. Abraço. Em tempo: também inclui o texto da pergunta fora do código pra facilitar encontrarem o problema.

Comment: Sobre a pergunta, não sei se entendi bem, mas pra fazer sem atualizar a página vc pode usar ajax.

Comment: Não acredito ser uma duplicata. No link referenciado por @GuilhermeLautert o usuário queria executar php no javascript, aqui ele quer "saber" se existe forma compatível em javascript ou html de executar um equivalente de php. Bom em html não mesmo! Acho que fica claro se tratar de um carregamento dinâmico

Comment: gsutavovox, agradecido pela sua orientação e discernimento!

Comment: Lauro Moraes, agradecido pela interpretação exata da minha pergunta!